# Como recibir notificaciones remotas con Firebase

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy intentando recibir notificaciones con firebase. Estoy enviandolas con Cloud messaging de Firebase. Envio el mensaje pero no aparece en la bandeja de notificaciones.

Haciendo pruebas e implementado el siguiente metodo en el AppDelegate que si recibe el mensaje pero no como notificacion en background que es lo que yo quiero hacer.

```
public func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage){
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
    //let title = remoteMessage.appData[("data"): {"title"}]
    let title = "New Request"

    for value in remoteMessage.appData{
        if let value = value as?  [AnyHashable:Any]{
            print(value)
        }
    }

    let message = "okay"
    print(message)
    print(title, message)

}
```

¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ? ¿ Porque no aparecen las notificaciones en la bandeja de notificaciones ?

Comment: La push notifications van a mostrarse y aparecer en la bandeja cuando la app no este abierta. Si tienes la app abierta sí llega la notificación pero no se muestra, si quieres que se muestre como cuando alguien te manda un mensaje en WhatsApp tienes que hacer una UIView personalizada y poner el código para desplegarla dentro del método que pusiste.

Comment: Tengo la aplicación abierta en background. ¿ Quieres decir entonces que en background debo hacer también una UIView con notificación local ?

Comment: Ah no, si la app esta en background debe llegar como notificación normal del sistema, si no esta llegando puede ser un problema de configuración

Comment: Ok, volveré a mirar las configuraciones, puede que los certificados los haya creado mal

Comment: Hola Abraham!!! Bienvenido me alegra que te hayas decidido aportar a [es.so]! Termina el [tour] para que obtengas tu primera medalla y siempre basate en [answer] para las respuestas. Que alegria ver un conocido por acá :D

Comment: Gracias KacosPro!

Comment: Alfinal creo que es un problema de certificados que subo a Firebase o que incluyo en el proyecto de XCode iOS. He probado con otra aplicacion que tengo el mismo codigo y me llegan las notificaciones en background. Pero en esta nueva aplicacion no funciona a pesar que Firebase me indica que el estado del mensaje es Finalizado. Cuando a la nueva aplicacion le pongo el mismo bundle Identifier que otra aplicacion que tengo funcionando con push notifications esta me funciona. ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ? ¿ Como se si los certificados que voy creando son correctos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se bien los pasos que hayas seguido para activar las notificaciones, te los menciono rápidamente la secuencia a seguir , para ubicar si ha faltado alguno:

Crear la llave de autenticación

1. En la cuenta de desarrollador de Apple, ve a Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, y en Keys selecciona All.
2. Haz clic en el botón de añadir (+) en la esquina superior derecha.
3. Ingresa una descripción para la llave.
4. En Key Services, selecciona el checkbox de APNs y haz clic en Continue.
5. Haz clic en Confirm y después en Download. Guarda la llave en un lugar seguro.

Instalar la llave de autenticación en firebase

1. En el proyecto de firebase selecciona el icono de engrane y haz clic en Settings.
2. Ve a Cloud Messaging
3. En la configuración para iOS en la APN Authentication Key selecciona Upload.

Configurar el AppID

1. Ve a tu cuenta de desarrollador -> App IDs y selecciona el AppID correspondiente, haz clic en Edit
2. En los servicios selecciona el checkbox Push Notifications.
3. Haz clic en Done.

Añadir notificaciones a tu proyecto

1. En XCode habilita las notificaciones push en App>Capabilities.
   En caso de marcar error en el provisioning profile vuelve a descargarlo porque se actualizó con las características de notificaciones.

Instalar el SDK

1. Añade los pods a instalar en el PodFile como sigue: pod ‘Firebase/Core’ pod ‘Firebase/Messaging’
   Ejecuta pod install
   Cierra y abre nuevamente el projecto de xcode.

En el AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    //TODO Confirm if this is the right point to initialize Push Notifications
    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]

    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in})
    } else {
        // iOS 9 or before
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    // [END register_for_notifications]


    return true
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID iOS10: \(messageID)")
    }
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler(.alert)
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    completionHandler()
}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("NOTIFICATION: Registration token  =>  \(fcmToken)")
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("NOTIFICATION: Received data message => \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("[RemoteNotification] didRefreshRegistrationToken: \(fcmToken)")
}
```

}

Comment: Muchisimas gracias !! Alfinal me funciono pero lo hice de la manera antigua. Saque 2 certificados .p12 uno para desarrollador y otro para distribucion en vez de sacar solo un .p8 con la opcion de la key.  Tambien creo que tenia el proyecto creado mal o corrompido pues tuve que crear uno nuevo